# Cleanup on Docker container kill

Tags: node.js, redis, docker, socket.io

I wish to have a multi docker container setup running nodejs with socket.io.
I am using redis for some shared socketId/state. When I kill a nodejs process I have a cleanup function executed to remove the sockeId/state accosiated with the process.

```
process.stdin.resume();//so the program will not close instantly

function exitHandler(options, err) {

console.log('exitHandler');

_.forEach(global.sockets, (socket)=> {
    if (global.redisClient) {
        global.redisClient.hdel('socketA', socket);
        global.redisClient.hdel('socketB', socket);
        global.redisClient.del(`socketC_${socket}`);
    }
});

_.forEach(global.userIds, (userId)=> {
    if (global.redisClient) {
        global.redisClient.hdel('socketD', userId);
        global.redisClient.del(`socketE_${userId}`);
    }
});

if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
if (err) console.log(err.stack);
if (options.exit) process.exit();
}

//do something when app is closing
process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, {cleanup: true}));

//catches ctrl+c event
process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));

//catches uncaught exceptions
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
```

This works well when the node is not running in a container. When it's in a container and I kill the container the cleanup is not executed. I suppose the container is killing all the communication pipes before I can do the cleanup. Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: you may try external heartbeat control.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the idea/process I am a newbie on docker

Comment: you need a monitoring container, watch your workers and whenever one exit, do the cleanup. also there are some events triggered by docker daemon itself when a container shutdown. if it helps i can explain more

Comment: Yes please, I need to be notified with in the node.js process. Why is process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true})); not doing its job ? Do you know what event I should be listening to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for `SIGTERM`. When you run `docker stop <container>`, It will send a `SIGTERM` to container and wait for 10 seconds. If container doesn't stop in meanwhile, it will send a `SIGKILL` to kernel to finish the container up.

Recommended reference: [Gracefully Stopping Docker container](https://labs.ctl.io/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

So, from the container inside, you should listen for `SIGTERM`. from outside, you can use docker API to check if your container killed and do the correct job: [Monitoring Docker Events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/)